# Why does this JS function style not work in retrieving the required data

Tags: javascript

I have two JS functions doing the same thing:

1)

```
var person = {
    firstName: 'John',
    surname: 'Jones',
    dob: new Date('1990-01-01'),
    isMarried: false,
    age: function() {
        return new Date().getFullYear() - this.dob.getFullYear();
    }
};
```

2)

```
var person = {
    firstName: 'John',
    surname: 'Jones',
    dob: new Date('1990-01-01'),
    isMarried: false,
    age: () => {
        return new Date().getFullYear() - this.dob.getFullYear();
    }
};
```

Notice that the only difference between the two pieces of code is how the age() function is described. As I understand, the former is using a function statement and the latter is using a function expression.

The issue is however, that only the former piece of code returns the expected data, whereas the latter returns the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFullYear' of undefined
    at Object.age
```

I am trying to understand why one works and the other doesn't when both are syntactically correct?

I've just started out learning JS in depth so detailed yet straight-forward answers would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: var person2 = {
    firstName: 'John',
    surname: 'Jones',
    dob: new Date('1990-01-01'),
    isMarried: false,
    age: () => {
        return new Date().getFullYear() - this.person2.dob.getFullYear();
    }
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As I understand, the former is using a function statement and the latter is using a function expression*

No both are function expressions. The only difference is that the first is normal function and second one ES6 Arrow Function.According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function **expression** is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although **without its own bindings to the `this`**

Arrow function doesn't have their own `this` bindings to this and it will use the `this` binded to the parent scope. In above case parent scope is global scope. So `this` will refer to `window` object not to object.

```js
const obj = {
  method:() => console.log(this === window)
}

obj.method()
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on where the `this` comes from in the arrow function.

Answer (score 1):

As described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), arrow functions do not bind to `this` (in addition to other keywords). In your second case, `this` is undefined, resulting in the TypeError.